# Is ASM a regular language?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, context-free, regular-expressions

I'm giving a presentation where I have a single slide dedicated to formal languages. In this slide I give a simplified overview of the Chomsky Hierarchy and I'd like to give an example of a real world language for each tier in the hierarchy.

For recursively enumerable languages I've chosen C++ because in theory its template system [allows for infinite recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419853/is-c-a-recursively-enumerable-language) (even though gcc does have a recursion limit).

For context sensitive languages I've chosen C, because its [sensitive to pre-declared constructs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/7717/90183), but AFAIK you can't get the compiler to go into an infinite loop when attempting to recognize if a C program has valid syntax.

For context free languages I take a few liberties and I give Python as an example even though [Python is not context free](http://trevorjim.com/python-is-not-context-free/), its closer to context free than it is to context sensitive.

Then we come to regular languages. I initially couldn't think if anything "real-worldy" off the top of my head, but then I considered assembly language. It seems like that might be regular. There isn't any nesting, its just a list of instructions. It seems like you could construct a regex that determines if a string is a valid ASM program.

Let A be the regex that matches a address
Let R be the regex that matches a register
Let K be the regex that matches a constant

Ignoring comments (which should be easy to include) for each command we can make a regex `C A|R|K A|R|K ...`, depending on the specific args that command C is allowed to take. AFAIK it is syntactically valid to chain any sequence of commands so we could write a gadget G that looks like `(C1 | C2 | ... | CN)\n*`, which effectively matches any command. A label can be L = `\w+:\n*`, so then a regex that accepts an ASM program might look something like: `(L | G)*`

Is that valid? Did I miss anything, or am I correct in using ASM as an example of a regular language?

Comment: Not a research questions but good examples come from the **lexical** level of programming languages. Examples: what's an identifier in Java, what's an integer, what's a float in Python? Examples: [Java’s lexical spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-3.html) and 
[Python 3’s lexical spec](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). Lexer generator mannuals also give examples, eg [JFlex](https://jflex.de/manual.html).

Comment: I’ve never worked with a true assembler, but my understanding is that assemblers commonly include support for macro syntax that can be quite powerful. For example, the code at the end of the paragraph at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language#Support_for_structured_programming does not look at all like a regular language.

Comment: If you use labels then ASM is not regular. But I think it's a good example: without labels and other "facilitations" (like macros or  inline math expressions) then it's "quite regular" :-). Other examples (but less known/used) could be: the actual machine code of a microprocessor ("pure" ASM is a 1:1 map to it), the bytecode (java or others) and many [esoteric languages](https://esolangs.org/) or Code-Golf languages; some of them are simply $L = \Sigma^+$ (every string from the alphabet is a valid program)